# Android RelativeLayout onClick

Tags: android

how can i change the background of a relative layout?
I have a custom RelativeLayout class:

```
public class PersView extends RelativeLayout {


private TextView name;
private ImageView photo;
private RelativeLayout rl;




public PersView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public PersView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public PersView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}



private void init() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.persview, this);
    this.name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    this.photo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
    rl= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RLpersview);


    /*rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            photo.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
            name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            name.setTextColor(Color.RED);



                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }

        );*/


    }


}
```

and here's the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/RLpersview"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_selector">





<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:src="@drawable/caputo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Giancarlo Caputo"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#BF000000"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/photo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

All works fine if I keep the relative layout empty, but it seems that the imageview and the textview "cover" the background

Comment: What does it mean to create custom class ?

Answer (score 0):

just add padding to relative layout, so the user can see the selector effect on relative layout

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried, it works but I don't like it too much ;-)